# How to correctly dismiss a modal View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

Inside my Custom TabBarController I set the NavigationController for each tab

```
let viewController = [HomeViewController(), ProfileViewController()]
let navControllers = viewControllers.map { return UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0) }
setViewControllers(navControllers, animated: false)
```

In my HomeViewController I have a CollectionView that when selecting a cell it pushes my VideoPlayerViewController to the NavigationController. The VideoPlayerViewController then presents a ViewController as a modal:

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func presentPopover() {
        let popoverViewController = PopoverViewController()
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        popoverViewController.delegate = self
        present(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In my PopoverViewController I have a close button that calls the delegate method in the VideoPlayerViewController:

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    @objc func closeTapped() {
        delegate?.willClose(self)
    }
}

extension VideoPlayerViewController: PopoverViewControllerDelegate {
    func willClose(_ viewController: PopoverViewController) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When calling dismiss on my PopoverViewController it not only dismisses the modal ViewController but it also pops the VideoPlayerViewController from the NavigationController and it returns to the rootViewController (HomeViewController).

I want to go back to the VideoPlayerViewController and only dismiss the PopoverViewController without popping the VideoPlayerViewController.

Comment: Try dismissing `PopoverViewController ` in `closeTapped `. By the way, do you present or push `VideoPlayerViewController` when selecting a cell?

Comment: @mahan I'm pushing `VideoPlayerViewController` to my `NavigationController`. I tried dismissing the `PopoverViewController` directly in the `closeTapped` but I still get the same results.

Comment: In your code, you have `PopoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`  with uppercase P, is this mistake or are you setting this on the class instead of on an instance?

Comment: @JakubSkořepa Thanks for pointing that out it was a typo I have it correctly in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the dismiss on your VideoPlayerViewController. This should be done on the PopoverViewController as below:

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    @objc func closeTapped() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing that it does the same thing. It throws me back to the rootViewController of the NavigationController, instead of just going back to the VidePlayerViewController.

Comment: Could you please share the code how you present the PopoverViewController ?

Comment: It's up there, I just Initialize the PopoverViewController and present it using `present(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` inside my VideoPlayerViewController